# Access data using URL and fragment in python

Tags: python, url, web, screen-scraping

I would like to get the historical prices from this and similar sites using python:

http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en/etfs/db+x+trackers+msci+world+information+technology+trn+index+ucits+etf+LU0540980496/price+turnover+history/historical+data

Loading this in python is giving me only access to the first 50 rows. In the browser I could set the start and end date and click through all further pages, but how can I do this automatically?

I understand that this information (page number, start and end date is sent via the browser using fragments, so for example this loads the second page:

http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en/etfs/db+x+trackers+msci+world+information+technology+trn+index+ucits+etf+LU0540980496/price+turnover+history/historical+data#page=2

However, I can't get this to work in python, i.e. this still gives me the first page:

```
url = 'http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en/etfs/db+x+trackers+msci+world+information+technology+trn+index+ucits+etf    +LU0540980496/price+turnover+history/historical+data#page=2'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
```

Also, I don't know how to even change the start and end date via the url, let alone load this into python.

I uploaded the code I have so far here: http://pastebin.com/thPHttw6

I would like this to produce the timeseries for any given start and end date.

Comment: In the normal course of events, the fragment is never sent to the server. As you can see using (e.g.) the Web Developer plug-in for Firefox, his site is using JavaScript (jQuery actually) to retrieve additional content and update the page. Your best approach is going to be to analyze how it's requesting the data for the additional page and do likewise.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure how to do this or even where to start looking. Can you get me started on where to look up this kind of stuff?